# Ajax.PageHandlerFactory Error Handler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm having trouble with code related errors coming through despite `customErrors="remoteOnly"` being set. Is there an event I can tie into to capture the error when a method signature doesn't match? I'm using MS AJAX library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diving through the code of the AJAX library using Reflector, it looks like this is by design. While it's not returning a true ASP.NET error, it is encapsulating the exception error message into a bit of JS returned in the response stream. Unfortunately it looks like this behavior is not modifiable.